# Node Pattern Rubocop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

Can't figure out how to match the node pattern for enum options.

Code I want to match, enum that has prefix: true (or scoped: true for later versions):

```
enum bla: { active: 0, not_active: 1 }, _prefix:true
```

Will get **node** as:

```
ruby-parse -e 'enum bla: { active: 0, not_active: 1 }, _prefix:true'

(send nil :enum
  (hash
    (pair
      (sym :bla)
      (hash
        (pair
          (sym :active)
          (int 0))
        (pair
          (sym :not_active)
          (int 1))))
    (pair
      (sym :_prefix)
      (true))))
```

**My pattern:**

```
'(send nil? :enum (hash (pair (sym {:_prefix :true}))))'
```

Tried out a bunch of versions without sym and nil/_.

What I'm doing wrong in this matching? Do I Need to skip nodes before the prefix node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [any order `<>`](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop-ast/node_pattern.html#for-match-in-any-order) for keyword argument lookups:

```
(send nil? :enum (hash <(pair (sym :_prefix) true) ...>))
```

Also, the `true` in this pattern means a node that is `true_type?`, thus a node corresponding to a literal `true` in Ruby.

You can see [it in action](https://nodepattern.herokuapp.com/?p=(send%20nil%3F%20%3Aenum%20(hash%20%3C(pair%20(sym%20%3A_prefix)%20true)%20...%3E))&ruby=def%20example%0A%20%20enum%20bla%3A%20%7B%20active%3A%200%2C%20not_active%3A%201%20%7D%2C%20_prefix%3Atrue%0Aend%0A)